# String answer1 = "yes"; if (answer1 == "yes") gives false. Why?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your name");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Is "+ name + " really your name?");
        String answer1 = scanner.nextLine();
        if (answer1 == "yes"){
        System.out.println("Alright ");
        }else  {System.out.println("Liar!");
    }
    }
}
```

It outputs `Liar!` even though I typed `yes`, so that `answer1` equals `yes`. Why?

Answer (score 4):

Because with `==` you are testing reference equality, not value equality. [Good reading.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Instead `answer1 == "yes"` do `answer1.equals("yes")`.

Comment: @user2864545 No problem, welcome to SO. You can mark this answer as accepted by  clicking that tick on the left.